# Algorithm for maximum value of a continuous function

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Are there any algorithms for finding the maximum value of a continuous function, which is proofed to be bounded upside?

For example, a function similar to sin.

I think Newton's method and Mid-point method are for finding a fixed value, any other methods for finding maximum value?

Comment: Unless you make some more assumptions about the function, you're going to have to try all of the values.

Comment: Is the function continuous? Otherwise, you'll have a hard time finding the maximum of `f(x) = 100 if x equals pi, 0 otherwise`

Comment: This is a very broad topic under the general heading of "optimization". Voting to close as too broad. Suggest editing your question to provide more detail about the specific use case.

Comment: Is this a one dimensional function ? If not, is it a concave function ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a function? Are you searching for a local or for a global maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general functions that are "Lipschitz-continuous" (meaning that the output changes by at most a constant factor times the change in input) see e.g. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00938542#page-1 and http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9937-9#page-1 . If your function is arbitrary continuous and not Lipschitz-continuous, then in theory the function could change to an arbitrarily high or low value over an arbitrarily small region, so provable global optimization is very hard.